# Alfresco: CMIS web services binding: Why alfresco gives cmis:item by protocol cmis 1.0?

Tags: alfresco, cmis

I'm trying to get a document from Alfresco 5.2 using CMIS web services binding (http://server:8080/alfresco/cmisws/cmis?wsdl) and get an error.
Using the wireshark I found that the problem is that the alfresco in the response returns cmis:item element. But according to cmis 1.0 protocol it should not be returned. Why is this happening?

Request:

```
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
<soapenv:Header>
<wsse:Security 
xmlns:wsse="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-secext-1.0.xsd" soapenv:mustUnderstand="0">
<wsu:Timestamp 
xmlns:wsu="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-utility-1.0.xsd">
<wsu:Created>2017-10-06T15:33:27.634Z</wsu:Created>
</wsu:Timestamp>
<wsse:UsernameToken>
<wsse:Username>admin</wsse:Username>
<wsse:Password wsse:Type="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-username-token-profile-1.0#PasswordText">0000</wsse:Password>
</wsse:UsernameToken>
</wsse:Security>
</soapenv:Header>
<soapenv:Body>
<ns2:getTypeDescendants xmlns:ns2="http://docs.oasis-open.org/ns/cmis/messaging/200908/" xmlns="http://docs.oasis-open.org/ns/cmis/core/200908/">
<ns2:repositoryId>53131d3f-d80b-4964-87d9-08b614fe7861</ns2:repositoryId>
<ns2:depth>-1</ns2:depth>
<ns2:includePropertyDefinitions>false</ns2:includePropertyDefinitions>
</ns2:getTypeDescendants>
</soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>
```

Response(part):

```
<soap:Envelope xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
<soap:Body>
<getTypeDescendantsResponse xmlns="http://docs.oasis-open.org/ns/cmis/messaging/200908/" xmlns:ns2="http://docs.oasis-open.org/ns/cmis/core/200908/">
<types>
<type xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:type="ns2:cmisTypeItemDefinitionType">
<ns2:id>cmis:item</ns2:id>
<ns2:localName>item</ns2:localName><ns2:localNamespace>http://www.alfresco.org/model/cmis/1.0/cs01</ns2:localNamespace>
<ns2:displayName>Item Type</ns2:displayName>
<ns2:queryName>cmis:item</ns2:queryName>
<ns2:description>CMIS Item</ns2:description>
<ns2:baseId>cmis:item</ns2:baseId>
<ns2:creatable>false</ns2:creatable>
<ns2:fileable>false</ns2:fileable>
<ns2:queryable>false</ns2:queryable>
<ns2:fulltextIndexed>true</ns2:fulltextIndexed>
<ns2:includedInSupertypeQuery>true</ns2:includedInSupertypeQuery>
<ns2:controllablePolicy>true</ns2:controllablePolicy>
<ns2:controllableACL>true</ns2:controllableACL>
</type>
```

Comment: Why are you using the WS* binding? It's very much the worst of all the CMIS bindings! What happens when you switch to AtomPub or Browser Binding?

Comment: Is the CMIS WS binding even supported in 5.2 for CMIS 1.1?